# Keycloak redirects localhost and not redirect remote url

Tags: java, web, redirect, server, keycloak

I have my Keycloak server and my web app connected with to Keycloak to do the login into the app.

If I run in local, its redirects perfectly, but if I deploy the server and the web app in the same server, when the web app redirects to keycloak it redirects to localhost not to the remote url.

Any idea how to avoid redirects to localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found an answer that fits better in my case. I created a KeycloakConfigResolver class, where I load a KeycloakDeployment depending on the host of the machine where is running, like that it redirects perfectly to the desired host.

```
@Configuration
public class PathServerKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver
{
  @Override
  public KeycloakDeployment resolve(Request request)
  {
    String hostname = "Unknown";

    try
    {
      InetAddress addr;
      addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      hostname = addr.getHostName();
      return KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(getKeycloakJson(hostname));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  private InputStream getKeycloakJson(String hostname) throws IOException
  {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/keycloak.json");
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String str;
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      sb.append(str);
    }

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().replace("{param_keycloak_server}", hostname).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }


}
```

Where the keycloak.json is,

```
{
  "realm": "FocusocKeycloak",
  "auth-server-url": "http://{param_keycloak_server}:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "login-app",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "XXX"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot Web app redirect URL is defined in properties as:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
```

If you have JSON config file, then it will look like:

```
{
  ...
  "auth-server-url" : "http://localhost:8080/auth"
}
```

For more detailed info you may take a look at [Securing Apps](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html) documentation

Comment: I have this configuration, but the problem is that whemn is deployed in a remote server if I try to access into the app, it redirects me to "localhost" but in the remote server and my browser try to access "localhost" (local machine)

Comment: When deploying to a remote server you should set URL of the remote server. So in production code, your configuration should look like  `keycloak.auth-server-url=${KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URL}`. And then you should define environment variable like
`KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URL=http://remote.server.com/auth` for your remote server.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Muhammed-sidhin/Keycloak.git

This is the official Keycloak Docker image for development. It's based on Keycloak Official Docker Image, starting with keycloak-15

This configuration is working